# "No definition found for `User is on NetBanking Login Screen`" warning shown in feature file of Cucumber

Tags: java, eclipse, cucumber

Below are my feature, Step definition and test runner files. step definition file has all keywords as per feature file, it shows warning No definition found is displayed in feature file. I am able to run the code, all print statements from step definition file are printed in console but some error also displayed in red color. [image: Folder structure is added for reference]

Feature file:

```
Feature: Application Login
  Scenario: Home page default login
  Given User is on NetBanking Login Screen
  When User login into application with Username and Password
  Then Home page is displayed
  And Cards are displayed
```

Step definition:

```
package StepDefinition;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class stepDefinition {
    
    @Given("^User is on NetBanking Login Screen$")
    public void user_is_on_netbanking_login_screen() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Login screen appears");
    }

    @When("^User login into application with Username and Password$")
    public void user_login_into_application_with_username_and_password() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Login with Creds");
    }

    @Then("^Home page is displayed$")
    public void home_page_is_displayed() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Home page appears");
    }

    @And("^Cards are displayed$")
    public void cards_are_displayed() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Cards are displayed");
    }

}
```

Test runner:

```
package cucumberoptions;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features",
        glue = "StepDefinition"
        )

public class testrunner {

}
```

Comment: Can you *show* us the error message?

Comment: Warning message in feature file is "No definition found for `User is on NetBanking Login Screen`"
Below error message is displayed in console along with output of print statments.
[32m[1m┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐[0m
[32m[1m│[0m Share your Cucumber Report with your team at [36m[1m[4mhttps://reports.cucumber.io[0m          [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m Activate publishing with one of the following:

Comment: Case matters. CucumberOptions refers to "StepDefinition" while your type name is "stepDefinition".

Comment: In CucumberOptions, i have refered to the package ('StepDefinition') under which test runner file 'stepDefinition' is available.